# Can't access doubly nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have comments which belong to answers which belong to questions. I'm currently trying to show the comments but I get an error:

```
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

apparently from this line
    <%= render @answer.comments %>

My form for comments looks like this

```
<%= form_for([@answer, @answer.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
</p>
```

And my comments controller looks like this

```
def create
@answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
@comment = @answer.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to answer_path(@answer)
end
```

Comment belongs_to answer and answer has_many comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should create the comment as itself and relate it to your answer:

```
@comment = Comment.create(answer_id: params[answer_id])
```

GL & HF.

Comment: Still get an undefined method error, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is your params hash? Your new method in your controller?

Comment: def create
  @comment = Comment.create(answer_id: params[:answer_id])
   redirect_to answer_path(@answer)
 end

Comment: I don't have an new action in controller since the answer page renders a form for submitting information to create a comment-

Comment: But your controller doesn't find is `@answer`. How does your route look like?

Comment: resources :questions do
      resources :answers 
    end

    resources :answers do
      resources :comments 
      end

Comment: ugh, do you have a repository where I could sweep the code or something? Edit your question to include your whole controller at least.

Comment: Controllers are here, https://github.com/edgarw19/question_app/tree/master/app, I would love any help, I've been banging at this for days now.

Comment: I checked out your code, @google1254 and you should read some introduction to rails (maybe [Rails for zombies?](railsforzombies.org)). For starters you have only the create method on your comments controller. As such non-conventional code, I couldn't quite understand the expected behavior of your app (I didn't _study_ it, but gave it a few minutes) and can't really figure out your ´problem. I suggest you check out a few tutorials and come back with a new question, because right now you don't seem to understand what you're asking (making it really confusing). I'll still try to help though. GL.

Comment: Alright, thanks a bunch, I'm new and trying to learn by doing, but I think I'm at a point pushing ahead is working, but it's with very bad style and convention. I'll check out rails for zombies, I really appreciate your suggestion.